# Only Rook endgame!

Tags: endgame, puzzles, rooks, rook-endgame

Is it possible to win (black or white) in this position?

```
[fen "2k5/5R2/8/4K3/r7/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it possible to win (black or white) in this position?

Of course it is. Both black and white have mating material. They each have a rook but a victory for either of them would require the opponent to blunder. For instance if white were to play Rc7 blundering the rook then black can force checkmate and if black were to play Re4 white could take and again force checkmate.

Either player could also inexplicably resign which would also end the game in favour of the opponent.

However with reasonable play by both sides it is a draw.

Comment: Also, a player could lose by letting themselves get mated, e.g. in this position 1.Kd6 Kd8?? 2.Rf8#

Comment: Also, one or both players might be very low on time (which is the only conceivable reason to play on, but I consider this as bad style).

Answer (score 0):

At best play it is a draw, though it is possible for either white or black to win because both of them have a rook. Though, for either side to win, the other side would have to blunder or, obviously, resign.

Comment: . . . or lose on time (as @Hauke Reddmann suggests in a comment on another answer), or forfeit in some other way.

Comment: The point of adding a new answer is not simply to repeat what another person has said. In the future, please read the other answers before posting yours.